# Erro como @ManyToMany (com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method) - JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Galera,

estou tento problema para alterar senha de um funcionário, no meu ManyToMany está dando um erro: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method

Alguém pode me ajudar?

FuncionarioBean

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "tbl_funcionario_has_tbl_projeto", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_funcionario_fun_codigo") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "tbl_projeto_pro_codigo") })
private List<Projeto> projeto;
```

Entidade Projeto

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name = "pro_codigo")
private Long pro_codigo;

@NotEmpty(message = "O campo Tipo � obrigatorio.")
@Column (name = "pro_tipo")
private String pro_tipo;

@NotEmpty(message = "O campo Projeto � obrigatorio.")
@Column (name = "pro_projeto")
private String pro_projeto;

@NotEmpty(message = "O campo Superior Imediato � obrigatorio.")
@Column (name = "pro_superiorImediato")
private String pro_superiorImediato;
```

XHTML:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/modeloGeral.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <div id="redefinir">
            <h:form>
                <input type="hidden" id="idFunc" name="idFunc"
                    value="#{param['id']}" />
                <div class="senha">
                    <div class="row2">
                        <p:outputLabel class="nova_senha" value="Crie uma nova senha" />
                        <br /> <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row_center">
                        <div class="row3">
                            <p:outputLabel class="label_senha" value="Crie sua nova senha: " />
                            <br />
                            <p:password class="password" size="35" maxlength="20"
                                value="#{funcionarioBean.novaSenha}" required="true"/>
                            * <br /> <br />
                            <p:outputLabel class="label_senha"
                                value="Confirme sua nova senha: " />
                            <br />
                            <p:password class="password" size="35" maxlength="20"
                                value="#{funcionarioBean.novaSenhaConfirma}" required="true"/>
                            * <br /> <br />
                        </div>
                        <h:commandButton class="botao" value="Confirmar"
                            actionListener="#{funcionarioBean.gerarSenha}"
                            update=":frmLoginGeral" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Coloca o log de erro completo

Comment: Provavelmente é nulo ou é lançada uma *lazy exception*. Sem mais detalhes do contexto é difícil falar a melhor forma de solucionar, pode ser desde usar *eager* (se SEMPRE precisa ser carregado), *join fetch*, inicializar antes, etc.

Comment: Pô cara deu certo! Obrigado.